# Will a subclass catch block catch a checked parent exception?

Tags: java, checked-exceptions

I have a method with a checked exception for a parent class, which can throw exceptions of the type parent and subclass

```
public void method() throws ParentException {
    if( false ) throw new ParentException();
    else if( true ) throw new ChildException(); // this one is thrown
}
```

and I have a cascade catch block, which first has the child exception

```
try {
    method();
} catch (ChildException e) {
    // I get here?
} catch (ParentException e) {
    // or here?

}
```

Which block will catch the exception thrown? Since the method declares explicitly the ParentException only, would the ChildException be shown as an instance of ParentException?

Comment: Why in the world does this question have so many downvotes?

Answer (score 20):

The `catch` block will always catch the most specific exception available to it, working its way up from the inheritance hierarchy.

I should stress that your catch blocks ***must*** be in the inheritance hierarchy order; that is to say, you may not declare a `catch` block with `ParentException` followed by `ChildException`, as that is a compilation error.  What you have there (in terms of `catch` blocks) is valid.

A more common use case of this is when handling file IO; you can first catch `FileNotFoundException`, then `IOException`, should the error be less specific than `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: so it would go in the first, performing something like an internal instanceof?

Comment: @Sajhu yes, it will go into the first catch clause.