# Catching subclass of exception

Tags: java, exception

I'm testing some things about exception handling in Java 8. When a try-catch block is used, the `catch` clauses are supposed to contain *only* exceptions that are thrown in the `try` block.

**Correct usage:**

```
try {
    throw new IOException();
} catch (IOException e){
    // do something - this code will be activated
} catch (Exception e){
    // do something - this code will not be activated
}
```

The `IOException` catch clause matches the thrown exception in the `try` block and will execute its code. If the `IOException` catch clause becomes omitted, then the `Exception` catch clause will activate because `IOException` extends `Exception`. This is very basic stuff.  What I don't get is why the following code also compiles:

```
try {
    throw new Exception();
} catch (IOException e){
    // do something - this code will not be activated
} catch (Exception e){
    // do something - this code will be activated
}
```

In this case, the most generic base-level exception is thrown. The thrown exception does not match `IOException` and will be handled by the `Exception` catch clause as a result.  But I had expect the compiler to warn me that the `IOException` catch clause is invalid because I neither throw it in the `try` block nor do I call a method that throws an `IOException`.

If I change the thrown exception to something that `IOException` doesn't inherit from:

```
try {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
} catch (IOException e){  // compiler complains about this line
} catch (Exception e){
}
```

then the compiler correctly tells me that the IOException is never thrown in the `try` block and is thus invalid. Does this have something to do with an `Exception` base class having the potential to contain an `IOException` instance and having it match on that?  Following that line of reasoning, does this mean that:

```
try {
    Exception exception = new IOException();
    throw exception;
}
```

will be caught by the `IOException` catch clause?

Comment: or maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38442108/will-a-subclass-catch-block-catch-a-checked-parent-exception